# how to implement event listeners in mvc architecture js?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to make the 'next' button work using the MVC architecture but for some reason, I get no response when clicking on it.
I have imported the 'nextQuestion' function to controller.js as the 'Publisher & subscriber design patterns' suggests and nothing works.

///////// CONTROLLER //////////

```
const init = function () {
  nextQuestion(showQuestion);
};
init();
```

/////////// VIEW //////////////

```
export const nextQuestion = function (handler) {
  const nextQuestionBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn");
  nextQuestionBtn.addEventListener("click", handler);
};
```

I have tried to place

```
" const nextQuestionBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn"); "
```

in the global scope to troubleshoot but I get no response for my clicks.

tried so many different things, no success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, probably your controller isn't seeing your view. Try logging something inside your nextquestion method and execute your controller if there will be any change.

Comment: I solved that already with event delegation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

After using insertAjesentHtml, the button looses connection to the query selector supposedly. So I solved it with event delegation first but it seemed like a wrong way to do that. So I have abstracted the button from the insertAjesentHtml function so I wont insert it over and over again every time.
hope it make sense.